# responsive 2 column 2 row layout

Tags: css, html, layout, responsive-design

I have been trying to figure out how to create this layout, I have a 2 column layout with the left column having 1 row and the right side having 2. Im trying to get it to adjust fluidly. What im having trouble with is I would like the top of the top image on the right to align with the top of the left image while the bottom of the bottom image stays aligned with the bottom of the left image. Should I use a table?

here is what I have so far.. not very close I really appreciate the help.

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=TpsEptHKit

here is an image of what I would like to acomplish [image]

Comment: If any of the answers solve your problem, please accept the relevant answer. Many people spent their time working on the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could come up with was a table with a single row and two cells (so both sides would be equal in height).

Then on the right we have two `div`s with heights adding up to 100% (say, 60% for the top and 40% for the bottom).

We'll specify `vertical-align: top` for the upper block, and `vertical-align: bottom` for the lower one. On top this will produce the desired effect, but on the bottom the vertical align doesn't kick in properly because we only have one element to align. To fix this, we need a spanner element with 100% height and place this adjacent to the "real" block.

Here, `.block` would represent the content inside the cell, e.g. image and caption.

***[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b9n4/1/)***

**HTML**

```
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="left">
        </td>
        <td class="right">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="block"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="filler"></div><div class="block"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px;
}
.right {
    height: 100%;
}
.right .top {
    height: 60%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.right .bottom {
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
.filler {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: No, No, No No No! Tables are for data, and nothing else. You should achieve the same thing using CSS table layout, which is supported even in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RGaw5/

```
<div id="left-container">
<div id="left" class="black"></div>
<p class="description-text-left">Printed Lexington</p>
</div>
<div id="right">
<div id="right-top" class="black"></div>
    <p class="description-text">Printed Lexington</p>

<div id="right-bottom" class="black"></div>
<p class="description-text">Printed Lexington</p>
</div>
```

You can make it responsive by giving the width in vw or %.

EDIT:  Here's a responsive, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RGaw5/1/

EDIT 2: Note that the first column's height can vary - no matter what's the height, the rest of the divs will scale accordingly. Here's one more fiddle with a different left column's height: http://jsfiddle.net/RGaw5/2/

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is first wrap the whole thing in a container, than give your `.right:{float:right}` and remove the `float:left` in other classes. See the code

```
.container{
    width: 620px;
    height: 400px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.blackBox {
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 175px;  
}

.redBox {
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

This looks the same as your pic: http://jsfiddle.net/aC7j6/1/