# Responsive 2 column 3 block layout without javascript

Tags: html, css, grid, frontend, responsive

I'm having issues creating a responsive 2 column layout with three blocks.

I am trying to create the following: (ignore text, just the blocks)
[image]

With it looking like this on mobile:
[image]

I looked into different resources and adapted code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025582/responsive-2-column-2-row-layout) to produce what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/RGaw5/42/

```js
$("#right-top").css({'height':($("#left").height())/2});

$("#right-bottom").css({'height':($("#right-top").height()-'0')});

$("#right-bottom").css({'top':($("#right-top").height() +'20')});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0;
}

#left-container {
width: 50vw;
    float: left;
}

#left {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    
}
#right-top {
    width: 50vw;
    float: left;
}

#right-bottom {
    width: 50vw;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-container">
<div id="left" style="background-color:red"></div>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="right-top" style="background-color:green"></div>
    <div id="right-bottom" style="background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea to do this efficiently responsively without jQuery?

Comment: Use bootstrap. Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. It includes predefined classes for easy layout options, as well as powerful. Get it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/